# Как получить данные, которые вводит пользователь на странице логина?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Пишу небольшой проект на Spring, есть главная страница ввода логина, где при правильном вводе данных юзера дальше перебрасывает на страницу приветствия.

Мой вопрос - как мне получить данные, которые ввел пользователь, чтобы дальше ими оперировать реализуя определенную логику? Дело в том, что помимо юзернейма и пароля есть еще несколько полей и именно данные с них я хочу получать для проверки

БД в проекте нет, правильный логин и пароль лежит в application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ для тест-проекта сделать какой-то класс для хранения таких данных
class Storage {
public static Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
}

Ну и хранить себе там данные. В момент запроса просто кладите туда что-то и в нужный момент доставайте
Strorage.data.put("Field1", "Here some data");
Storage.data.get("field1");